# Magento: frontend user login not working

Tags: php, magento

I have an existing magento project. User login always worked fine but suddenly whatever I try I get an error. I tracked the problem down and found that in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php at line 425 that

```
$this->getPasswordHash()
```

is empty. Has anyone ever experienced this and could give me a hint as to why this is happening? I tried resetting the password, but that didn't help at all.

Comment: I would suggest switch to default/default theme, try logging in and check what parameters and url it is requesting in browser network. later switch to your theme and check the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it turns out, I was trying to override the Customer.php model with 2 different extensions. So the handling of the user login in Extension A was ignored in favor of Extension B and that's why it didn't work any more. As a solution I merged the two extensions so that there was only one overriding Customer.php and now it works again.